# Always on Server Disks

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

Have sql server always on configured with 2 replicas as asynchronous mode with no automatic failover.
But total capacity of log file disk on primary is less than the secondary server disk.Folder structure is same but the disk capacities are different.
Plan will be to increase the disk space on primary as well. But will it cause any latency or other issues in the meantime? Please advise.SQL version is 2017.

Answer (score 1):

You should have no problem if you are happy with the projection for log file growth in Primary (current).

But in case you failover the replica role, you have to manage this differently. It will depend on your workload and what is the duration before you can failback to the original configuration.

The example I think of is to limit the max file size for logs if you have to failover before making your disk size the same on all nodes. I am sure there are other ways to manage this; monitoring log file usage and alerting if a threshold is reached.